# How to solve SSL error issue while downloading data from wikipedia through Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am trying to download average population data from wikipedia page(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India) & wrote the below code:

```py
import requests
website_url=requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India').text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')


print(soup.prettify())
```

The error I am getting is as follows :

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wiki/Demographics_of_India (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

How to solve the above issue ?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55746814/httpsconnectionpool-ssl-error-certificate-verify-failed?

Comment: Nope I am not running any proxy